# Shape of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I came across this piece of code

`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print("Shape of x_train: " + str(x_train.shape))
print("Shape of y_train: " + str(y_train.shape))`

And found that the output looks like this

`(60000, 28, 28)
(60000,)`

For the first line of output

So far my understanding, does it means that in 1st dimension it can hold 60k items, then in next dimension, it can hold **28** "*array of 60k items*"
and finally, in the last dimension, it can hold **28** "*array of 28 "array of 60k items"*"

What I want to clarify is, Is this 60k samples of 28x28 data or something else?

For the second line of output, it seems like its just a 1d array of 60k items. So what does it actually represents? (i know that in x_train it was handwritten numbers and each number represents the intensity of grey in that cell)

Please note I have taken this code from some online example(i don't remember and won't mind if you want your credit to be added to this) and public dataset
`tf.keras.datasets.mnist`

Comment: `(60000, 28, 28)` == 60000 images of shape `28x28`. `(60000,)` == array of 60000 elements (integers in range 0-9 in this case). If you would have `(60000, 28, 28, 3)` it would mean that you have 60000 RGB images each one of shape `(28, 28, 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the first line gives 60K items of `28x28` size data thus `(60000, 28, 28)`.

The `y_train` are labels of the `x_train`. Thus they are a one dimensional and 60k in number.

For example: If the first item of the `x_train` is a handwritten image of 3, then the first item of `y_train` will be '3' which is the label.

Comment: I have worked with the MNIST handwritten dataset. So I am familiar with the same.

Comment: I found that this comment answered my question exactly what I was expecting (apologies for not putting down my question that well)
This answer also answered my subsequent questions which is why I am marking this as the answer.
Other answers are not incorrect they all are correct and gave me a more detailed idea about the dataset which I never thought of. Wish I could have marked all as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the shapes is correct. From the context probably the `x_train` are 60k images of handwritten numbers (with resolution 28x28 pixel) and the `y_train` are simply the 60k true number, which the images show.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, let's start with a 1d array of shape (8,).

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If this is represented as a 2d array, say of shape (4, 2), it becomes

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8]
]
```

See every item in the 2d array gets a shape of (2,) and there 4 items totally.

Let's represent in 3d with size (2, 2, 2).

```
[
  [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
  ],
  [
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
  ]
]
```

The array at the top level has 2 items which is the 0th dimension. The second level has 2 items again which are `[1, 2], [3, 4]`. The final dimension of size `2` denotes `1 & 2`, the last level of items in the array hierarchy.

Hence a tensor of (x, y, z) shape will contain `x*y*z` elements.